# How to grow bacteria?

Tags: bacteriology

We have this science experiment on how to grow a bacteria, our teacher told us to use gelatin, beef stock, and sugar as an alternative for agar. I am confused on  why we need gelatin, beef stock, and sugar in growing a bacteria. What ingredient is in those 3 materials that can aid in growing bacteria?

Answer (score 5):

There are several requirements for bacteria to grow.

- A carbon source - Sugar
- A nitrogen / amino acids source - Beef stock
- Gelatin is there to hold everything in place, it doesn't provide any nutrients.

Comment: The list is incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

Everything that lives needs food to grow. That food may be as simple as nutrients needed to build parts to more complex tasks like storing and/or converting energy.

Different bacteria require different things. A nutrient source like beef stock contains lots of amino acids and proteins which can feed a large spectrum of bacteria.

Sugar is a densely packed energy store that many bacteria can use for powering biologic processes.

Gelatin is a mixture of peptides and proteins which adds even more nutrients to the system. **More importantly**, its thick gelatinous structure acts as a binding agent/ substrate which keeps everything from sloshing around in the dish (which can be very inconvenient when moving it around).

In short the simple petri dish is about providing a wide variety of nutrients so that it can support the growth of a wide variety of microbes.

Comment: "Converting" rather than "producing" energy.

Comment: You know you could just edit it for a point that small

Comment: i only edit my own answers.